# Azure App Service with on-premise registry

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

Can Azure App Service pull container images from on-premises private registry like Sonatype Nexus?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine as long as you can provide a URL to that private registry, login and password.
[image]

If this Sonatype Nexus is available only from your private on-premise network and not exposed publicly, the only solution which I think will work is integrating app service with VNet and creating IPSEC into your private network.

With that solution you would need to set **WEBSITE_PULL_IMAGE_OVER_VNET** to **True** in app setting